# Is it correct to use “Entschuldigen mich” instead of “Entschuldigen Sie”?

Tags: verb, pronoun, grammaticality

*Entschuldigen Sie* means *excuse me*,

but *Sie* means in English *you* in English and *me* in German means *mich* or *mir*.

So why is it *Entschuldigen Sie* instead of *Entschuldigen mich/mir*?

Comment: Welcome to German.Stackexchange! I took the liberty to clarify the question, because I liked the question, but had to read it twice to understand it. If you don't like my editing, you can role it back to the old version here: http://german.stackexchange.com/posts/34640/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to distinguish between contextual translations and literal (word for word) translations.

The *contextual* translations looks at what a person of the other language would *say* in a certain context (using as many literal translations of words of the source as possible). In English, if for example you want to ask somebody a question you will say ‘excuse me.’ In the corresponding German situation, you would say ‘Entschuldigen Sie.’ Therefore, the contextual translation is correct.

*Literally,* you need to approach this differently; you need to take each word, identify its grammatical properties and then think what the direct translation is in the other language conserving the grammatical properties. Let’s do this with the English phrase first.

We have the words *excuse* and *me.* The first is a verb in imperative (second person) modus. The second is a direct object form of the pronoun *I.* The second is the first’s object which is grammatically required in this sentence. Translating this, *excuse* becomes a form of *entschuldigen* while *me* would become *mich* or *mir* — but since we know the verb, we can fix it to *mich (jemanden entschuldigen).* German now has *two* second person imperatives; one formal and one informal one. The informal one is easy, it just consists of the word *entschuldige.* Thus one literal translation of *excuse me* is:

> Entschuldige mich.

The formal imperative is slightly more complicated since the formal *Sie* is, grammatically, a third-person form. Therefore, the third-person pronoun *must* be part of the sentence. The formal literal translation therefore becomes:

> Entschuldigen Sie mich.

When doing the *reverse,* i.e. translating literally from German to English, we see *entschuldigen* and *Sie.* The first is a verb form of *to excuse* and could be one of many without context. The second could be either nominative or accusative of the formal second person pronoun — which is, as stated above, grammatically a third-person one. Along with the context information that this must be an imperative, we realise (see above) that *Sie* is grammatically necessary since only grammatical second-person imperatives can lose the pronoun. Thus, we need to take both words together and translate them as one:

> Excuse.

You read correctly, the literal translation of *entschuldigen Sie* is simply *excuse;* no mention in made *who* or *what* is to be excused.

For grammatical reasons, *entschuldigen mich* is wrong; I noted above that the third-person imperative requires its subject. You *can* use the informal *entschuldige mich* which would be grammatically correct. And you also *can* extend the formal imperative with the object (i.e. who is to be excused) — which would make it *entschuldigen Sie mich.*

Answer (score 2):

In German "Entschuldigen Sie" is the correct grammatical form. "Sie" is a substantive as it's the formal version of you. In German "Entschuldigen Sie" is a set expression like "excuse me" in English.

It is possible to say "Entschuldigen Sie mich bitte" which means please excuse me. This is used for example for the sentence: please excuse me at the office, I am sick. 
In German: Entschuldigen sie mich bitte im Office, ich bin krank.

If you use say "Excuse me, could you repeat that again" the German sentence is: 
"Entschuldigung, können Sie das bitte Wiederholen" or "Entschuldigen Sie bitte, könnten Sie das wiederholen". Here you could even leave "Sie" out.

Comment: You can only leave out the "Sie" if you switch from "Entschuldigen" (verb) to "Entschuldigung" (noun).

Comment: Sagt man wirklich inzwischen "Office" statt "Büro"?

Comment: *Sie* ist kein Substantiv sondern ein Pronomen. (Und nebenbei ist die englische Übersetzung von *Substantiv noun.)*

Answer (score 1):

"Entschuldigen Sie" just designates who should excuse something. In informal context it would be "Entschuldige" (the "Du" is not added).

You can say "Entschuldigen Sie mich" or short "Entschuldigen Sie" or "Entschuldigen Sie meine Kinder" oder "Entschuldigen Sie den Lärm".

"Entschuldigen mich" or "Entschuldigen mir" does not work, because verb and pronoun don't agree.

It works the same with other verbs: "Schauen Sie sich das an", "Nehmen Sie noch ein Stück Kuchen", "Fahren Sie bitte rechts ran".

Comment: Maybe a clarifying sentence concerning capitalized "Sie" (you, formal) and "sie" (=she) with small letters could be added.

Answer (score 1):

It is **incorrect** to use "Entschuldigen mich":

"Entschuldigen Sie" is an imperative. When you're addressing the other person as *Sie*, the imperative is always followed by "Sie":

- "Kommen Sie bitte" - *Please come*
- "Helfen Sie mir bitte" - *Please help me*

So the "Sie" in "Entschuldigen Sie" is just the subject of the imperative. When saying "Du" to the other person, the subject isn't explicitly stated, as in English:

- "Komm bitte" - *Please come*
- "Hilf mir bitte" - *Please help me*

Therefore, when you address the other person as "Du", you would be able to just say "Entschuldige" - *Excuse me*.

The *me* part of *Excuse me* is often left out in the German way of saying it, but there are circumstances where you can include it, which makes it "Entschuldigen Sie mich" (or, when saying "Du", "Entschuldige mich"): If you want someone to move aside, "Entschuldigen Sie mich" sounds better to me, but if you want to add an explicit request, just "Entschuldigen Sie" is better: "Entschuldigen Sie, ..."