# Best way to say "Excuse me" to get someone's attention

Tags: phrase, politeness

Consider the situation where I want to approach a stranger to ask for directions, or to locate the restroom, etc. In English this is simply *Excuse me* to get the other person's attention. In German, I have always been taught *Entschuldigung* or more formally *Entschuldigen Sie mir bitte*. I've only ever seen the dative version, but [this related question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34640/is-it-correct-to-use-entschuldigen-mich-instead-of-entschuldigen-sie) uses the accusative *Entschuldigen Sie mich*.

Which version of *Excuse me* is most appropriate or common for getting a stranger's attention? Are both the accusative and dative forms correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most common to an adult are

> - Entschuldigung[, können Sie mir sagen, wie ich von hier aus zum
>     Bahnhof komme?]
> - Entschuldigen Sie[, können Sie mir sagen, wie ich von hier aus zum
>     Bahnhof komme?]
>
> Upper style:
>
> - Verzeihung[, können Sie mir sagen, wie ich von hier aus zum
>     Bahnhof komme?]
> - Verzeihen Sie[, können Sie mir sagen, wie ich von hier aus zum
>     Bahnhof komme?]

and to a child:

> Hallo[, kannst du mir sagen, wie ich von hier aus zum
>   Bahnhof komme?]

*»Entschuldigen Sie mir«* is ungrammatical (as a call to get attention), *»Entschuldigen Sie mich«* isn't used at all in this context.

Answer (score 7):

Both versions are wrong or at least unusual in your context.

`Entschuldigen Sie mir bitte` would be the correct case in that special context as you could continue the sentence like `, dass ich Sie störe` and then you need dative.

But normally when addressing somebody you would completely omit the pronoun:

`Entschuldigen Sie bitte` is the normal way to say this.

The other case `Entschuldigen Sie mich bitte` is also quite common in Germany, but it means something different:

If you are in a meeting or talking to someone and you need to go away (either for a short time as going to the toilet or leaving completely) then you use that phrase to say that you are sorry to interrupt the meeting / talk. This often is also used if you just interrupt because you need to pick up the phone as someone "very important" calls you.

Short answer:

**Entschuldigen Sie mir bitte** - incorrect or at least unusual

**Entschuldigen Sie bitte** - you ask someone for attention

**Entschuldigen Sie mich bitte** - you say sorry for taking your attention away from that person (go away, pick up a phone, etc.)

Comment: "Entschuldigen Sie **mir** bitte" is so uncommon, I would not even mention it here for being afraid that someone would ever use it by mistake. Especially not as the first occurrence.

Comment: It was mentioned in the question, so I think the anwer should say something about it.

Comment: "Entschuldigen sie mir bitte die Stoerung" is not at all uncommon where I'm from.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but since "Entschuldigen Sie" literally translates to "Excuse you," is there a way of saying "Pardon me" if you're squeezing past a person in a tight space or something? Or just use "Entschuldigen Sie bitte"?